# Constraint-less Parse query returns blank objects

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I've usually been making queries to a class for a single, directed object using the objectId and it's all been working smoothly. However I am now trying to get *all* of the objects in a given class.

```
        var values;
        var Class = Parse.Object.extend(className);
        var query = new Parse.Query(Class);
        console.log(objectID);
        if (typeof objectID !== "undefined") { //if the user specified objectID
          query.get(objectID, {
            success: function(retrieveObject) {
              for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                values[i] = query.get(keys[i]);
              }
            },
            error: function(error) {
              console.log("Failed to retrieve " + className + ': ' + error.message);
            }
          });
        } else { //if not return all
          query.limit(1000);
          query.exists("objectId");
          query.find({
            success: function(results) {
              console.log("the results are " + results);
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < keys.length;j ++)
                console.log("key " + j + " is " + keys[j]);
                console.log("the result for " + j + " is " + results[i]);
                var object = results[i];
                values[i][j] = object.get(keys[j]);
                console.log("the value for the key in result is " + values[i][j]);
              }
            },
            error: function(error) {
              console.log("Failed to retrieve " + className + ': ' + error.message);
            }
          });
        }
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this does not work. "results" comes out as an array of the correct number of values, but each is "[object Object]"

Any ideas?

Comment: Should there be a code block following `for (var j = 0; j < keys.length;j ++)` ?  Your inner for loop looks a little broken.

Comment: Also where is `keys` defined?

Comment: Finally, [object Object] is what you would expect. For the purposes of debugging, you could print it out, `console.log(JSON.stringify(results[i])`

Comment: @adrian why would I expect [object Object]? Shouldn't it be of the type that I requested? Do I have to do some sort of cast to the class that I want it in?

Comment: Javascript is loosely typed, so there isn't really a notion of casting here. The parse query method actually returns a list of Parse.Objects, it doesn't have any understanding of what your specific Class type is.

Comment: Some Parse.com SDKs, for example the iOS SDK, do allow you to inherit from the Parse Object base type, and you can then do nice things like myParseClass.keyName = "foo", however this isn't possible in the Javascript SDK.

Comment: But shouldn't results[i].get(keys[i]) return the value for a given key? I don't see why this wouldn't work? And why it works in the previous function when I query for a specific objectId

Comment: You'll need to address my first 2 comments first. I'm not sure where 'keys' is defined, and your inner for loop looks like it is missing some braces.

Comment: Oh my god. I'm an idiot. Keys is defined fine, but oh my god I can't believe I forgot the block after the for loop. Thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72238/discussion-between-tuckerchapin-and-ardrian).